# Laravel 5 dingo api, add multiple transformed objects to the response

Tags: laravel-5.1, dingo-api

Want to add a transformed object along with other response, I have used following code:

```
$accessToken = Authorizer::issueAccessToken();

    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('username'))->with('profile')->first();
    if ($user) {
        $accessToken['user'] = $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer);
    }

    return $accessToken;
```

Expected Response:

```
{
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "data": {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "xxxxx",
      "profile": {
        "data": {
          "id": 1,
          "first_name": "Muhammad",
          "last_name": "Shakeel",
        }
      }
    }
}
```

but not getting transformed object, there must be some better way to add multiple transformed objects with response. Am I missing something?

**Edit**
Current response returns user object without transformation and if I return only user transformed object like following, it returns correct transformed object:

```
return $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer);
```

Comment: you probably need fractal package https://github.com/gathercontent/laravel-fractal. This package is awesome https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository

Comment: dingo-api already uses fractal for transformations

Comment: What is the response that you're getting right now then? Are you getting the user atleast?

Comment: @BharatGeleda Current response returns user object without transformation and if I return only user transformed object (question edited), it returns correct transformed object.

Comment: Have you tried te defaultIncludes that Fractal Transformers provide?

Comment: @BharatGeleda fractal transformers and includes works perfectly when we only return the transformed object as response the problem is to add some other non-transformed values to response. Means I need to send response of user transformed object along with accessToken array keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on the issue tracker(https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/743#issuecomment-160514245), jason lewis responded to the ticket with following:

The only way you could do this at the moment would be to reverse that. So you'd return the response item, then add in the access token data, probably as meta data.

So, something like this.

```
return $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer)->setMeta($accessToken);
```

The response will then contain a meta data key which will contain your access token data.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using Internal Requests. https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Internal-Requests

So what you can do is

Suppose you have a route that fetches transformed user object at `api/users/{email_id}?access_token=...`

While issuing the access_token you can do the following :

```
$dispatcher = app('Dingo\Api\Dispatcher');
$array = Authorizer::issueAccessToken();

$array['user'] = $dispatcher->get('api/users/'.$request->get("username").'?access_token='.$array['access_token']);
return $array;
```

This will return transformed data.

**NOTE** : **You will need to have a route that fetches user data.**

**You will have to handle cases in `/api/users/{email-id}` where email-id does not exist.**

Comment: Thanks @BharatGeleda, I'll try it out today.